# Does $\varprojlim\ ^1$ vanish whenever it doesn't have to account for non-right exactness of $\varprojlim$?

Tags: limits, homological-algebra, derived-functors, exact-sequence

The projective limit functor is not right-exact: if $G_\bullet\rightarrowtail H_\bullet\twoheadrightarrow K_\bullet$ is a projective system of extensions, then there is a long exact sequence
$$
0\to\varprojlim G_\bullet\to\varprojlim H_\bullet\to\varprojlim K_\bullet\to\varprojlim\ ^1 G_\bullet\to\varprojlim\ ^1 H_\bullet\to\varprojlim\ ^1 K_\bullet\to\cdots.
$$
Is there an example of a projective system of extensions $G_\bullet\rightarrowtail H_\bullet\twoheadrightarrow K_\bullet$ such that the map $\varprojlim H_\bullet\to\varprojlim K_\bullet$ is surjective and such that the term $\varprojlim\ ^1 G_\bullet$ is non-zero?

Comment: Please excuse the ugly way of typesetting the derived projective limit. The command \limits does not seem to work here.

Comment: Sure, better! I'll go ahead and delete my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. For example, take any $G_\bullet$ for which $\varprojlim\ ^1 G_\bullet$ is non-zero, and consider the projective system $G_\bullet\rightarrowtail G_\bullet\twoheadrightarrow 0$, where the first map is the identity.